# Is there another use for Valor Points?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I read today a [Dev Watercooler article](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/blog/4736886) in Blizzard's site, regarding the plans they had back then for Mists of Pandaria:

> In Mists of Pandaria, Valor will be used to power a new feature that
>   allows you to increase the item level of your existing epic items.
>   This means that each week, you can become a little more powerful,
>   hopefully allowing you to kill that boss that has eluded you thus far.
>   There will be a bit of a game in trying to decide when to upgrade your
>   gear versus hoping for a new piece to drop from a raid boss, but our
>   plan is that even heroic gear can be upgraded slightly in this way.

(3rd paragraph, section "**The Future of Valor**")

Now that Mists of Pandaria is live, I haven't seen any NPC or anything like that that serves that purpose. Was this implemented? Scraped? To be released content?

Comment: upcoming patch: http://www.mmo-champion.com/content/3010-Item-Upgrades-Update-HoF-Progression-Blue-Posts-Setup-of-the-Month-MMO-Report

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be released in the upcoming patch (5.1). According to [this](http://wow.joystiq.com/2012/11/06/patch-5-1-ptr-upgrading-items-with-justice-and-valor/#continued) post.